# KeyListener won't work

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I try to test my graphic program by create a circle then add key listener on them and make them work.

But I seen it does not work! But the graphic work well!

So, can you correct the code for me?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*; //AWT extends

public class dotMoveByArrow extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

    Timer t = new Timer(5, (ActionListener) this);
    double x = 0, y = 0, velX = 2, velY= 2;

    public void dotMoveByArrow() {

        t.start();
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponents(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        Ellipse2D circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, 40, 40);
        g2.fill(circle);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        repaint();
        x += velX;
        y += velY;
    }

    public void up() {

        velY = -1.5;
        velX = 0;
    }

    public void down() {

        velY = 1.5;
        velX = 0;
    }

    public void left() {

        velX = -1.5;
        velY = 0;
    }

    public void right() {

        velX = 1.5;
        velY = 0;
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {

        int key = event.getKeyCode();
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {

            up();
            System.out.println("up");
        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {

            down();
            System.out.println("down");
        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {

            left();
            System.out.println("left");
        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {

            right();
            System.out.println("right");
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {}

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        dotMoveByArrow d = new dotMoveByArrow();
        JFrame f = new JFrame();

        f.getContentPane().add(d);
        f.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        f.setUndecorated(true);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(640, 480);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setTitle("Dot Move by Arrow");
    }
}
```

Comment: Regarding: "So, can you correct the code for me?" -- It's much better for you if you follow our suggestions and correct your code *yourself*. I suggest that you Google and use key bindings, not a KeyListener for this. There's a decent tutorial you can easily find on this, and many, many examples to be found in forums such as this one (several written by me). Luck.  **Edit:** Here's the tutorial link: [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Answer (score 3):

One issue of your code is that you have defined a method

```
public void dotMoveByArrow() { ... }
```

which maybe was thought to be the constructor

```
public dotMoveByArrow() { ... }
```

(note that there is no `void` in the declaration).

The method is never called in your code and therefore the listener is not registered at all.

Comment: @GrimReaper Welcome to StackOverflow! Please click the checkmark next to the answer which you see best answers the question. This gives credit to whoever provided the correct answer and tells other users the question has a valid solution. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

The `dotMoveByArrow` method is never called, so your listener is never added. If `dotMoveByArraow` is supposed to be a constructor, then it should be declared as

```
public dotMoveByArrow()
```

without the `void` return type. Java classes, by convention, always start with an upper-case letter. Hence, constructors also start with an upper-case letter.